# Exception in grails dbm-update - NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: grails, groovy, data-migration

When I run `"grails dbm-update --dataSource=production"` I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'sessionFactory_production' is defined
    at grails.plugin.databasemigration.MigrationUtils.findSessionFactory(MigrationUtils.groovy:142)
    at grails.plugin.databasemigration.MigrationUtils.getDatabase(MigrationUtils.groovy:105)
    at _DatabaseMigrationCommon_groovy$_run_closure2_closure11.doCall(_DatabaseMigrationCommon_groovy:52)
    at grails.plugin.databasemigration.MigrationUtils.executeInSession(MigrationUtils.groovy:133)
    at _DatabaseMigrationCommon_groovy$_run_closure2.doCall(_DatabaseMigrationCommon_groovy:51)
    at DbmUpdate$_run_closure1.doCall(DbmUpdate:25)
```

It works on the default dataSource (if I run "grails dbm-update"), but doesn't work on production or on my custom data source.

I use Grails 2.4.3 and database-migration:1.4.0.
I'm running it on Amazon AWS - RDS MySql DB.

Here's my dataSource:

```
production {        
   grails.dbconsole.enabled = true      
   dataSource {             
      grails.dbconsole.enabled = true           
      username = "myusername"           
      password = "mypassword"           
      pooled = true             
      dbCreate = "none"             
      driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"             
      url = "jdbc:mysql://mydatabase.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/ebdb?autoReconnect=true"          dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect             
      properties {
         validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
         testOnBorrow = true
         testOnReturn = true
         testWhileIdle = true
         timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 1800000
         numTestsPerEvictionRun = 3
         minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 1800000
      }          
   }
}
```

Comment: I once had weird issues on different consoles on windows (cmd or powershell). There it works only with cmd. But you can also use the notice in [DBM Docu](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-database-migration/docs/manual/ref/Update%20Scripts/dbm-update.html). There you have to quote the parameters

Comment: maybe only a copy and paste error, but is the dialect really in the same line as the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The item you are refering to as `production` is not a datasource but the config for the regular dataSource in the `production` environment.  So this call should work:

```
grails prod dbm-update
```

Comment: what about custom environment? I have to use "grails -Dgrails.env=mycustomenv dbm-update" ?

Comment: @user2153912 i can not speak from experience, but i would assume, that this works, as the env is handled very early on and dev/test/prod are just some shortcut for the most common cases.  so it works for prod but not your env?  errors?

Comment: yes, it works this way also for the custom environment. thanks.